# push_back a new element to a vector

Tags: opencv

http://pastebin.com/DL0iuS6N that is my WallFinder.h file and http://pastebin.com/3H9Hb19F is my WallFinder.cpp file.

My problem is that I would like to insert a new element to lines vector. However When I wrote lines.push_back(Vec4i((*it2)[0],yaxis,xaxis,yaxis)); after calling writeToFile function. I got error message that Assertion Failed! Expression:_CrtIsValidHeapPointer(pUsrData)

How can i insert to new element to my lines vector or What is my problem?

Answer (score 2):

As I see in your code, it2 is iterator on 'lines'. But when you perform push_back operation to vector you turns all the iterators to it invalid. This is the source of your problem.

Comment: OK. How can we solve this problem. I must add some new elements to this vector to do my project.

Comment: Use "for(unsigned int j=0; j<lines.size(); j++)" and instead of (*it2) use lines[j]. This will always be valid.

Comment: @user2923864 Please consider the possibility to accept the answer of Michael Burdinov if you find it useful. Thank you.